# Java - Can't edit byte array contents?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, byte

```
    byte[] stuffA = {69,96,13,37,-69,-96,-13,-37};
    for(int x = 0; x < stuffA.length; x++){
        if(stuffA[x] < 0){
            System.out.println("Somethin be up yo! ");
            System.out.println("This number be negative! " + (int)stuffA[x]);
            stuffA[x] = (byte)((int)stuffA[x] + 256);
            System.out.println("I added 256 and now stuff is positive yo! " + stuffA[x]);
        }
    }
    return;
```

When I run this, my output is:

```
Somethin be up yo! 
This number be negative! -69
I added 256 and now stuff is positive yo! -69
Somethin be up yo! 
This number be negative! -96
I added 256 and now stuff is positive yo! -96
Somethin be up yo! 
This number be negative! -13
I added 256 and now stuff is positive yo! -13
Somethin be up yo! 
This number be negative! -37
I added 256 and now stuff is positive yo! -37
```

What is happening?

Comment: What do you think the range of values you can store in a byte is?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Java Language Specification, section [4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges: For `byte`, from -128 to 127, inclusive.

So, `-69 + 256 = 187 = 0x000000BB` cast to byte is `0xBB = -69`.

Answer (score 1):

A byte has a range between -128 and 127 (-2^7 to 2^7-1) Adding 256 its like doing a 360 degree turn . Change 256 to 128 in your code and in will show different results

Answer (score 0):

`byte` is only 8 bits, so can only hold 2^8 = 256 values. It is signed in java so the values are in the range of [-128,127] inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

A `byte` can hold 256 differnet values. If you add 256 the byte overflows, and the result stays the same.
In java the range is [-128, 127].

Answer (score 0):

A byte can hold `256` different values, so when you add 256 you are making a `Rol (Rotate left) 8 times`, which returns the same value as previous.

If your desire is to transform `-69` in `69`, why you simply don't make a `stuffA[x] *=-1`?

If you really want to reverse the bits, you can use `complement operator` (`~`), `stuffA[x] = (byte) ~stuffA[x];`, but due to the `two's complement form`, to get the same number as previos you need to `add 1`,

like  `stuffA[x] = (byte) ((~stuffA[x]) + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

byte is 8 bits and integer is 32 bits

basically looking at bits:

byte b = -37 is equivalent to 219(int) whose binary is:

```
0000 0000 0000 1101 1011
```

int 256:

```
0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
```

adding both will give int value of 475:

```
0000 0000 0001 1101 1011
```

now convert it to byte i.e. take LSB 8 bits will be:

```
1101 1011
```

which is -37

Hope this explains